# Adobe Premiere scripting

Tags: scripting, automation, adobe-premiere

I want to automate a sequence of task on Adobe Premiere Pro CS6,
thats all repeating tasks, and while doing manually consumes lots of time, :)
that stars from: importing video file, image files, doc file-> making a sequence -> adding files on sequence with predefined height , width-> inserting scripts -> analyzing them -> adding marks on particular word on metadata-> and finally exporting it..

I want to make all these task automatically done with some scripts on adobe premier pro or anythign else...

appreciating

Comment: So what are you needing help with?  We answer questions, but we're not going to do the work for you.

Comment: I want to know, if there is any way of automating task or not?? if yes what kind of software or scripting i should follow...i can use adobe premier and its functionalities under mac, ...no platform independency needed..

Comment: It appears there is no way to automate in Adobe Premiere, since it does not have the scripting facilities that Photoshop, Illustrator, and other Adobe products have.

Answer (score 5):

Premiere is scriptable, as are the other Adobe Creative Suite apps, using their Extendscript API. Extendscript uses javascript. There's an official Adobe IDE for it called Extendscript Toolkit, that has a script editor, debugger and a object model viewer.

There's one problem, for premiere the documentation is perplexingly scarce. It's a pity, because for other programs like After Effects there is a thriving community of developers doing amazing stuff with extendscript.

The Adobe Javascript guide is [here](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf) and some class information specifically for Premiere can be found [here](http://cssdk.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sdk/2.1/docs/WebHelp/references/csawlib/com/adobe/premiere/package-detail.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the PC platform, try having a look at a free windows automation package such a AutoIT or AutoHotKey. I have been using AutoHotKey for several years now and this tool can be used to automate pretty much anything you can think of.  It is a scriping language, there is a learning curve, but easy to use if you follow the many tuts and samples out there.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be officially supported, mentioned or used much (maybe because most user think programming is 'nerdy' stuff and don't touch it?) - anyways:

- http://forums.adobe.com/message/5310306

Unfortunately the documentation is scare and I don't know which version may support scripting (and which OS).